# Confusing queue implementation

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time understanding this implementation of a queue, more specifically the enqueue and dequeue methods.
I just can't get my head around it no matter how I approach it.

```
class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;

    Node(int x) {
        val = x;
        next = null;
    }
}

class Queue{
    Node first, last;

    public void enqueue(Node n){
        if(first == null){
            first = n;
            last = first;
        }else{
            last.next = n;
            last = n;
        }
    }

    public Node dequeue(){
        if(first == null){
            return null;
        }else{
            Node temp = new Node(first.val);
            first = first.next;
            return temp;
        }   
    }
}
```

How can the enqueue method work?
Here we're just 'forgetting' the last object, and setting it to the object n:

```
last.next = n;
last = n;
```

And how can this dequeue work if we've only touched the Node first once. How can first have a chain of `first.next` values?

```
Node temp = new Node(first.val);
first = first.next;
return temp;
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. The code looks perfectly normal. It seems you don't understand the basics of how linked lists work (this is language agnostic)

Comment: Similar to what @Ordous said, you're misunderstanding object references.  This [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html) explains how Linked Lists work (which is very similar to this Queue implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Here are step-by-step examples of how the methods work.

**enqueue**

n
one(first) -> two -> three -> four(last) // List before method call

```
last.next = n; // Add n to the end of the queue
```

one(first) -> two -> three -> four(last) -> n

```
last = n; // Update the last pointer - not modifying the list order
```

one(first) -> two -> three -> four -> n(last) // List after method call

---

**dequeue**

one(first) -> two -> three -> four(last) // List before method call

```
Node temp = new Node(first.val);
```

one(first, temp) -> two -> three -> four(last)

```
first = first.next;
```

one(temp) -> two(first) -> three -> four(last) // List after method call

Notice that `one` still points to `two`, however the pointer to `first` has been updated so there is no access to `one` any longer.

Answer (score 0):

The queue was implemented by a single linkedlist. The first and last are just two "pointers", pointing to the first and the last node in the list.

When enqueue was called, it will add(append) node to the list, when dequeue was called, the first node will be popped out. So the queue looks like:

```
n->n->n->n->...n  
linked list direction: ->
en/dequeue direction : <-
```

for example:

```
(first)F->2->3->L(last)
```

after `enqueue(E):`

```
(first)F->2->3->L->E(last)
```

after `dequeue():`

```
(first)2->3->L->E(last)
```

node `F` was returned.

the (first==null) check is just for checking if the queue is empty.

regarding this part codes, check the comments in line:

```
Node temp = new Node(first.val); //create a new node tmp, same value with first, but without "next"
first = first.next; //make the 2nd (first.next) as new first
return temp; // return the new created node (tmp)
```